# How to push Graphite metrics to Grafana Cloud with curl?

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I'm trying to get a very simple example of pushing Graphite metrics to Grafana Cloud using their HTTP API to work.

This example comes straight from the [Graphite HTTP API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/monitor-infrastructure/metrics/metrics-graphite/http-api/#example) documentation:

```bash
user_id=<USER_ID>
api_key=<API_KEY>
url=https://<SERVER_INSTANCE>.grafana.net/graphite/metrics

timestamp_now_rounded=$(($(date +%s) / 10 * 10))
timestamp_prev_rounded=$((timestamp_now_rounded - 10))

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $user_id:$api_key" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$url" -d '[{
    "name": "test.metric.tagged",
    "interval": 10,
    "value": 2,
    "tags": ["foo=bar", "baz=quux"],
    "time": '$timestamp_now_rounded'
}]'
```

When I run this script I get:

```json
{"status":"error","error":"authentication error: invalid authentication credentials"}
```

I am not sure which credentials to use. I have already tried creating a service account and a cloud access policy with write permissions, and none of the credentials seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Graphite HTTP API, you need to:

1. find the metrics url and user id
2. add a cloud access policy with a token that has write access to metrics

## User ID

1. Log into [grafana.com](https://grafana.com/auth/sign-in/?cta=myaccount) and click on the details of the hosted Graphite instance.
   [image: Graphite Details]
2. Copy the **URL** and **User**. User will be a 7-digit number. **This is the user id to use for your metrics query.** Do not click "Generate now" here; that will create a read-only token.
   [image: Grafana Data Source settings]
3. Scroll down to the attention box under **Sending data with Carbon-Relay-NG**, and click "Generate now". **This is your API key.** It actually creates a new token in your cloud access policy. You can add/edit/delete access policy keys by clicking `Access Policy` under the Security section in the left sidebar.
   [image: Generate write token]

With this user id and api key, you can make curl requests to your Grafana Cloud instance. You can then visualize the metrics by creating a dashboard connected to the `grafanacloud-<ORG_NAME>-graphite` data source.

---

References:

- https://pqvst.com/2021/06/22/hosted-monitoring-evaluating-influx-and-grafana/